# Empty space above the app bar

Tags: android, android-layout, screen

How do I get rid of the empty space shown below (the space between the horizontal red lines)?  I didn't see this on my app until getting a new phone (Samsung S8), which has more vertical screen space than my old HTC One.

[image: app screenshot]

The beginning of the layout file for that activity is:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout ...
```

My values-v14/styles.xml is

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

I tried googling this problem but I couldn't find anything -- I must be searching for the wrong terms.  What file do I need to edit to make the empty space above my app's action bar go away?

Edit: for comparison, here's what the app looks like in the emulator (it looks the same way on my HTC One):

[image: emulator screenshot]

I'd like the app to behave the same way as above (i.e. no black space above the action bar) when I run it on my Samsung S8. What do I need to change?

Comment: Isnt it Actionbar? I think Theme need to change to `NoActionBar` to use with toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening due to the wider aspect ratio of the Samsung Galaxy S8. By default, Android applications support a maximum aspect ratio of 16:9. To solve, add this element inside the `<application>` tag in your manifest:

```
<meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
```

Full details available in this Google blog post: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/03/update-your-app-to-take-advantage-of.html

Answer (score 2):

change this `<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

```
 <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

hopefully this will help you out , if not Kindly post your full xml file

happy to help

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a try and report back.

Comment: Using `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` didn't work:  it just caused the action bar (the bar that says "Probability Puzzles", below the lower red line) to disappear.  I want the empty space _above_ the action bar (between the two red lines) to go away.  Which xml file do you need to see?

Comment: Kindly post whole xml file of this layout