# Too much space between the appbar and status bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am making an app, where I want to use react navigation.
For some reason, whenever I use drawers in react navigation, there is a huge space between the status bar and the drawer app bar.

[image]

Here is my code for the ho -

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import * as React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import Header from "../Header";
import { Flexbox } from "../Layout";
import Card from "../Card";
import { marginAboveCard } from "../../constants/constants";
import Row from "../Row";
import { convertToIndianNumberingFormat } from "../../utils/utils";

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    const [cardsData, setCardsData] = useState({
        confirmed: 0,
        active: 0,
        recovered: 0,
        deceased: 0,
        tests: 0,
        critical: 0,
    });
    const [lastUpdated, setLastUpdated] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        const getData = async () => {
            const cardsDataResponse = await fetch(
                "https://disease.sh/v3/covid-19/all"
            );
            const cardsDataFetched = await cardsDataResponse.json();

            setCardsData({
                confirmed: convertToIndianNumberingFormat(
                    cardsDataFetched.cases
                ),
                active: convertToIndianNumberingFormat(cardsDataFetched.active),
                recovered: convertToIndianNumberingFormat(
                    cardsDataFetched.recovered
                ),
                deceased: convertToIndianNumberingFormat(
                    cardsDataFetched.deaths
                ),
                tests: convertToIndianNumberingFormat(cardsDataFetched.tests),
                critical: convertToIndianNumberingFormat(
                    cardsDataFetched.critical
                ),
            });

            const time = new Date(cardsDataFetched.updated);
            const lastupdated = time.toLocaleTimeString();
            setLastUpdated(`Last updated at ${lastupdated}`);
        };

        getData();
    }, []);

    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.main}>
            <View style={{ marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight }}>
                <StatusBar style="auto" />
                <Header text="COVID-19" />

                <Text style={styles.lastUpdatedText}>{lastUpdated}</Text>

                <View style={{ marginTop: marginAboveCard }}>
                    <Flexbox style={{ marginTop: 15 }}>
                        <Card
                            background="red"
                            title="Confirmed"
                            number={cardsData.confirmed}
                        />
                        <Card
                            background="#3877F0"
                            title="Active"
                            number={cardsData.active}
                        />
                    </Flexbox>

                    <Flexbox style={{ marginTop: marginAboveCard }}>
                        <Card
                            background="#47CC3C"
                            title="Recovered"
                            number={cardsData.recovered}
                        />
                        <Card
                            background="#868686"
                            title="Deceased"
                            number={cardsData.deceased}
                        />
                    </Flexbox>

                    <Flexbox style={{ marginTop: marginAboveCard }}>
                        <Card
                            background="#E85FEB"
                            title="Tests"
                            number={cardsData.tests}
                        />
                        <Card
                            background="#5BF8B6"
                            title="Critical"
                            number={cardsData.critical}
                        />
                    </Flexbox>
                </View>

                <View style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>
                    <Header text="TABLE STATISTICS" />
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
};

export default HomeScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    main: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: "#000232",
    },
    lastUpdatedText: {
        color: "white",
        textAlign: "center",
        marginTop: 12,
        fontSize: 15,
    },
});
```

My app.jsx -

```
import * as React from "react";
import HomeScreen from "./components/screens/HomeScreen";
import VaccineScreen from "./components/screens/VaccineScreen";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                <Drawer.Screen name="Vaccine" component={VaccineScreen} />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

If you look at the code of home screen properly, you would see a `status style` component which is set to auto. Even after removing it, the space is there. There are no errors in the console of any sort. This error started coming when I used react navigation drawer. Is there a way I can remove the space?

Comment: Try running the application on a physical device. You'll not see that space on a physical device. This `white space` problem has been there on the emulator for a while. For me, there's no space in the physical device but there is this space on the emulator. You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48960080/empty-space-above-the-app-bar/48960456) as a workaround.

Comment: yes the whitespace isn't there in the device but have you found out a way i can resolve the issue on the emulator? cheers! :)

Comment: Nope. Not as of now

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to move `StatusBar` as top most child like my sample below?

```
 ....
 <View>
    <StatusBar style="auto" />
       <ScrollView style={styles.main}>
          <View style={{ marginTop: Constants.statusBarHeight }}>
 ...
```

How you define the header title and the drawer icon?

Comment: wdym?? react navigation already puts the header title and the drawer icon.

Comment: Take a look at my sample https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/react-navigation---drawer-navigation-example, here you can see that the title i snot automatically added.